# Accessing web console in ActiveMQ 5.5.1

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.5.1 version. But I am not able to access the web console in this version using `http://127.0.0.1:8161/admin`. But the same can work in ActiveMQ 5.3.0 version. Also, I see that `jetty.xml` file (which exists in ActiveMQ 5.3.0) does not exists under `conf` folder.

Does anyone know how to access web console in ActiveMQ 5.5.1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just downloaded AMQ 5.5.1, started the activemq.bat file and successfully accessed localhost:8161/admin/

conf/jetty.xml does exist, for that matter.

Seems like your installation is corrupted. Consider download a fresh copy.

Comment: I too downloaded AMQ 5.5.1 now, it does contain conf/jetty.xml file. Let me check with this...